# Чи існує український аналог технічного терміну “hardware”?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, синоніми

Вікіпедія [каже](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) що

> Hardware або Апара́тне забезпе́чення — комплекс технічних засобів, який включає електронний пристрій і, зокрема, ЕОМ: зовнішні пристрої, термінали, абонентські пункти, тощо, які необхідні для функціонування тієї чи іншої системи; фізична частина ЕОМ.

Glosbe, [що](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/hardware) hardware це *обладнання* або *устаткування*, та додає:
*The physical components of a computer system, including any peripheral equipment such as printers, modems, and mouse devices |
Фізичні компоненти комп'ютерної системи, які включають периферійне устаткування, таке як принтери, модеми та миші*
Досить звужені поняття, але все ж таки є. 
Хоча може є інші варіанти перекладу?

І от, що цікаво, чи є українською аналог або синонім слів "апаратне забезпечення"?
Бо зустрічав у вжитку варіанти "залізо", "залізяки" тощо, проте, суб'єктивно, ці варіанти звісно не є оптимальними і, в принципі, не відображають суть терміну бо цей термін має на увазі саме комп'ютерне, а не якесь інше обладнання.

Comment: В ангійській мові термін hardware теж має багато значеннь - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware:

Computer hardware,
Household hardware,
Builders hardware,

тож люди з різним бекграундом можуть по-різному розуміти просто Hardware. Так само як і залізяччя у нас.

Answer (score 1):

#### Словники

> [Soft](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soft) - not hard or firm:
>
> - soft ground
> - a soft pillow/mattress
> - soft cheese
> - I like chocolates with soft centres.
> - Soft tissue, such as flesh, allows X-rays through.
>
> [Hard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hard) - not easy to bend, cut, or break:
>
> - a hard surface
> - There was a heavy frost last night and the ground is still hard.
> - Heating the clay makes it hard.
>
> [Ware](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ware) - pottery (= objects made out of clay) of a particular type
> or make:
>
> - Meissen ware
>
> [Software](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/software) - the instructions that control what a computer does;
> computer programs:
>
> - He's written a piece of software that does your taxes for you.
>
> [Hardware](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hardware) - the physical and electronic parts of a computer,
> rather than the instructions it follows
>
> [ЕЛЕКТРО́НІКА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0) - Сукупність електронних приладів.

Спробую знайти документальне підтвердження наступним термінам трохи пізніше:

Програми - сукупність певних програм.

Електроніка - сукупність певних пристроїв, приладів, виробів, що створені за допомогою електронних елементів як єдине ціле. Наприклад, відеокарта, системна плата, блок живлення, радіомодуль, перетворювач напруги тощо.

#### Я теж маю слово

Як бачимо з вище вказаних визначень soft - це щось не тверде, або ж м'яке. Hard - те, що не легко зігнути, порізати або розбити, тобто щось міцне. Ware - це певний посуд, або виріб.

Також в словниках вже вказано що таке software (команди, які керують що комп'ютер робить) та hardware (фізичні і електронні частини комп'ютера). Наче все просто і зрозуміло.

До чого ж тут м'якість та міцність? А це описове значення властивостей виробу. Тобто м'який виріб можна змінювати так, як потрібно. Саме таку властивість мають програми комп'ютера. А міцний, який не можна якось змінити, виріб ви не зможете змінювати (хоча по суті у вас є така можливість, змінювати, але не кожний має достатні знання для цього). Тому по суті маємо  такі дослівні наближені значення:

- hardware - міцний виріб;
- software - м'який виріб.

Я зрозумів, що люди, при спробі знайти переклад того чи іншого слова з англійської мови намагаються чомусь лише одне слово. В деяких випадках це можливо, а інколи - ні.

#### Чи існує український аналог технічного терміну “hardware”?

Ви вже самі навели подібне значення для hardware як "апаратне забезпечення".

#### Хоча може є інші варіанти перекладу?

Я використовую такі слова:

- hardware - електроніка, техніка;
- software - програми.

#### І от, що цікаво, чи є українською аналог або синонім слів "апаратне забезпечення"?

Немає такої потреби, або ж ви її не вказали. Ймовірніше є потреба в розумінні цього словосполучення з вашого боку.

#### ці варіанти звісно не є оптимальними і, в принципі, не відображають суть терміну

Щоб подібне стверджувати - треба якось це довести.

Comment: @Sasha "Чи не будуть електроніку (електронні пристрої) сприймати радше як сукупність hardware+software", можливо, але не з моєї точки зору. Електроніка є електронікою. Нею можуть керувати програми. Але електроніка - окремо, а програми, що керують електронікою - окремо. В електроніці можуть бути програми, а можуть і не бути.

Comment: @Sasha "До чого тут «міцна ємність, м'яка ємність» — не зрозумів." - hard - твердість, або міцність, ware - глиняна посудина, разом hardware - міцна ємність, або ж міцна посудина або щось схоже за значенням.

Comment: Ну, що ж, у випадку з автівками *техніка* може спрацювати, а що робити з *кухонними hardware*, наприклад виделками? або з *господарським hardware*, наприклад лопатами?

Comment: @Yola Не потрібно використовувати виделки чи лопати всередині комп'ютера. В комп'ютері може щось замкнути і згоріти.

Comment: https://householdhardware.nl/

Answer (score 0):

Хіба що "комплектуючі". [Пошук](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87%D1%96) видає дуже багато інформації.

"Залізо" для вузькоспеціалізованого тексту також підходить, але воно дуже неформальне.

Comment: Ось тут варіанти перекладу [комплектующие](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on).

Comment: "Комплектуючі" немає в словнику, але слово активно використовують. І саме воно для спеціалістів найбільш зрозуміле.

Comment: «Комплектуючі» [присутнє у «Словнику української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=182656&page=1368). «Залізо» [згадує Вікіпедія, зокрема наголошуючи на його сленговості](//uk.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Залізо_(значення)&oldid=21123519). Якщо додасте цю інформацію у відповідь, я думаю її сприйняття значно покращиться.